# MongoDB find when Isodate is Not a Number

Tags: javascript, mongodb, datetime, nan, isodate

So I have a full database, containing records with `begin_date` and `end_date` values of type `ISODate`.

An automated script does parse files and compute values for theses dates; but sometimes there was a problem, when for example file value was incorrect.

In these cases, I obtain this in database: `ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")`.

For now, I fixed the file parser, to put `""` in database instead of the wrong ISODate when there is parsing errors.

My problem is: How can I find all the documents in my database that have the wrong ISODate value; in order to replace them with `""` or remove them to be cleaner.

Example of what is my goal (using unexisting operator `$isNan`)

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {begin_date: {$isNan: true}}, 
    {$set: {begin_date: ""}}
);
```

I also tried something like:

```
db.collection.find({begin_date:ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")}})
```

```
2017-08-07T12:04:19.746+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: invalid ISO date :
ISODate@src/mongo/shell/types.js:65:1
@(shell):1:38
```

For now, I use this to find (but only works because I know that all my dates are after year 2000):

```
db.collection.find({begin_date:{$lt:ISODate("2000-01-01")}})
```

Comment: You mean `new Date(undefined)`, which is basically what happened to store the incorrect values in the first place.

Comment: Yes, or also `new Date("")` in mongo shell; like `new Date(undefined)` returning `ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")`. But I wasn't the one who stored the wrong values, I had to fix them.